# Gitlab pipeline - how to fail pipeline when Jacoco report coverage has a lower percentage than last commit in master branch?

Tags: code-coverage, gitlab-ci

Our team decide to define a task "done" when it meets several criterias. One of them is, "the coverage can never drop in comparison to last merge on master".

If we want to configure the pipeline so that it failed when the coverage drops, how could this be done? Now the coverage is shown in Gitlab merge request page but never used.

[image]